# Tag Profile Search is not working

Tags: search, crawling, tagging

- In Tag profile (under 'Tagged Items' tab) when I click on 'To find content related to 'I like it' in search, please click here.', it opens a search page with 'SocialTagId:"15254bd4-b81e-4a94-94f6-d22c0652eb14" in search bar.
- The page shows an error 'We did not find any results for SocialTagId:"15254bd4-b81e-4a94-94f6-d22c0652eb14".'
- Even though many items are tagged under said tag, still there is no search result.

What could be the problem here? Could it be that the indexing of tags not being done by crawler?

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your Content Hub is not setup properly.  The solution for this person (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/28c143cd-b154-4444-a806-475608ddd5d0/?prof=required) was to enable the Content Syndication Hub feature on the Site Collection, add that as the configured metadata hub in the Managed Metadata Service, reset the search index, and then re-crawl.